# Retrieve data from TextFormField from another widget to main

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 3 widgets in one another. The `TextFormField` is the last widget and i want to get the value input in the Form all the way back to the `main.dart` and i can't think of a way to do this.

Can someone help me please ? Screenshots are attached for reference.

I'm completely new to this so pardon me if i'm doing smth stupid.

```
 return Stack( // This is Main.dart
      fit: StackFit.expand,
         children: <Widget>[
             Positioned(
             top: 0.01 * widgetHeight,
             width: 0.99 * widgetWidth,
             left: 0.00 * widgetWidth,
             child: MySigninTextbox(),
   ),

 child: Container( // This is SigninTextBox.dart
                    child: TextBoxLogin(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        hintText: "Email",
                      )
                   )

child: TextFormField( //This is TextBoxLogin.dart
            onChanged: (val) {
              value = val;
              print(val);
            },
          )
```

[image: IMAGE 1] [image: Image 2] [image: Image 3]

Comment: You should not post your code in images... add the code in your question

Comment: Oh i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to pass arguments into the Class 'MySigninTextbox()', So make sure you set up the arguments for 'MySigninTextbox()', where you say is in the main, then just do this:

```
String forLoginVal = '';    

 return Stack( // This is Main.dart
          fit: StackFit.expand,
             children: <Widget>[
                 Positioned(
                 top: 0.01 * widgetHeight,
                 width: 0.99 * widgetWidth,
                 left: 0.00 * widgetWidth,
                 child: MySigninTextbox(forLoginVal: forLoginVal),
       ),

     child: Container( // This is SigninTextBox.dart
                        child: TextBoxLogin(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                            hintText: "Email",
                          )
                       )

    child: TextFormField( //This is TextBoxLogin.dart
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => forLoginVal = val)
                  print(val);
                },
              )
```